# union of redux action types still allowing unknown type in

Tags: typescript

I have created [this ts playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20type%20ErrorMessage%20%3D%20string%20%7C%20null%20%7C%20undefined%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20type%20Fetchable%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%20%26%20%7B%20error%3A%20ErrorMessage%2C%20isFetching%3A%20boolean%3B%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20type%20FetchableList%3CT%2C%20XS%3E%20%3D%20Fetchable%3CT%3E%20%26%20%7B%20items%3A%20XS%5B%5D%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20type%20ApiActionCreator%3CT%20extends%20object%2C%20Payload%20%3D%20object%20%7C%20any%5B%5D%20%7C%20undefined%3E%20%3D%20T%20%26%20%7B%20payload%3A%20Payload%2C%20error%3A%20ErrorMessage%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20Role%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20id%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20type%20RoleState%20%3D%20FetchableList%3C%7B%7D%2C%20Role%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20enum%20RoleActionTypes%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20GET_ALL%20%3D%20'%40%40role%2FGET_ALL'%2C%0D%0A%20%20GET_ALL_OK%20%3D%20'%40%40role%2FGET_ALL_OK'%2C%0D%0A%20%20GET_ALL_FAIL%20%3D%20'%40%40role%2FGET_ALL_FAIL'%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20type%20GetAll%20%3D%20ApiActionCreator%3C%7B%20type%3A%20RoleActionTypes.GET_ALL%20%7D%3E%3B%0D%0Aexport%20type%20GetAllOK%20%3D%20ApiActionCreator%3C%7B%20type%3A%20RoleActionTypes.GET_ALL_OK%20%7D%2C%20Role%5B%5D%3E%3B%0D%0Aexport%20type%20GetAllFail%20%3D%20ApiActionCreator%3C%7B%20type%3A%20RoleActionTypes.GET_ALL_FAIL%7D%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20type%20RoleActionCreators%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20GetAll%0D%0A%20%20%7C%20GetAllOK%0D%0A%20%20%7C%20GetAllFail%3B%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0Aexport%20const%20defaultRoleState%3A%20RoleState%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20isFetching%3A%20false%2C%0D%0A%20%20error%3A%20null%2C%0D%0A%20%20items%3A%20%5B%5D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20Action%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20type%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20AnyAction%20extends%20Action%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20Allows%20any%20extra%20properties%20to%20be%20defined%20in%20an%20action.%0D%0A%20%20%5BextraProps%3A%20string%5D%3A%20any%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20type%20Reducer%3CS%20%3D%20any%2C%20A%20extends%20Action%20%3D%20AnyAction%3E%20%3D%20(%0D%0A%20%20state%3A%20S%20%7C%20undefined%2C%0D%0A%20%20action%3A%20A%0D%0A)%20%3D%3E%20S%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20const%20roles%3A%20Reducer%3CRoleState%3E%20%3D%20(state%20%3D%20defaultRoleState%2C%20action%3A%20RoleActionCreators)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20switch%20(action.type)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20case%20RoleActionTypes.GET_ALL%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20default%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20state%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aroles(undefined%2C%20%7B%20type%3A%20'DO_SOMETHING'%20%7D)%3B) that shows the problem.

I have this type:

```
export type ApiActionCreator<T extends object, Payload = object | any[] | undefined> = T & { payload: Payload, error: ErrorMessage }
```

Which I want to use to create redux action types, for example:

```
export enum RoleActionTypes {
  GET_ALL = '@@role/GET_ALL',
  GET_ALL_OK = '@@role/GET_ALL_OK',
  GET_ALL_FAIL = '@@role/GET_ALL_FAIL'
}

export type GetAll = ApiActionCreator<{ type: RoleActionTypes.GET_ALL }>;
export type GetAllOK = ApiActionCreator<{ type: RoleActionTypes.GET_ALL_OK }, Role[]>;
export type GetAllFail = ApiActionCreator<{ type: RoleActionTypes.GET_ALL_FAIL}>;

export type RoleActionCreators =
  GetAll
  | GetAllOK
  | GetAllFail;
```

I then use that as an argument into my reducer:

```
export const roles: Reducer<RoleState> = (state = defaultRoleState, action: RoleActionCreators) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case RoleActionTypes.GET_ALL:
```

It will throw compile time errors for unknown case switch statements but it is still possible to call the reducer with an unknown action type:

`recducer(undefined, {type: 'DO_SOMETHING`}); // no error`

Is this possible with typescript?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is really very simple, `Reducer` has a second type parameter to represent the type of the action. Since you don't specify it on the variable type annotation, the type of the second parameter will not be preserved on the `roles` function and will be the default of `AnyAction`

This will trigger the expected error:

```
export const roles: Reducer<RoleState, RoleActionCreators> = (state = defaultRoleState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case RoleActionTypes.GET_ALL:
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

roles(undefined, { type: 'DO_SOMETHING' }); // err
```

Comment: the second generic argument to Reducer should cover that

Comment: @dagda1 not sure what you mean. The fact that you specified the type of the second argument to the function implementation will not impact in any way the second type argument to `Reducer`, which is unspecified in your code.